# Dispatch is not defined-ReatcJs

Tags: reactjs

I tried looking for answers from the sources that had same issue, but didnt work for my case.
I'm using this function to get some settings for my application:
js:

```
export function _someFun() {
    setData("abc").then(res => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTION.SET_USER_SUCCESS, res });
      }, (error) => {
        dispatch({ type: ACTION.SET_USER_FAILURE, error });
    });
}
```

where: `setData` is a function I'm importing from the Api file that basically sends a response to fetch the data. With the above call, its going into the success call but saying: "dispatch is not defined". Not sure how to get this working..any idea???

Comment: are you using redux? Dispatch is a part of the redux-store

Comment: try using `redux-thunk` so you can pass in `dispatch`

Comment: @ thsorens: yes, im using redux

Comment: Is this called within an component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install first the redux-thunk middleware:

```
npm install --save redux-thunk
```

Then, import an actionTypes object from the actionTypes.js file, that stores all the action types. Basically instead of ACTION you should use actionTypes. Is more explicit and clear that way.

And then try this in your action creator file:

```
export const setUserSuccess = (response) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: {
            response: response
        }
    }
};


export const setUserFailure = (error) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.SET_USER_FAILURE,
        payload: {
            error: error
        }
    }
};

export const _someFun = () => {
    // Using the redux-thunk middleware
    return dispatch => {
        setData("abc")
            .then(response => {
                dispatch(setUserSuccess(response));
            }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(setUserFailure(error));
        });
    }
};
```